# sqlalchemy + pyodbc how to trust certificate?

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I have a python script using pyodbc that connects to a remote server with sql server running on it. I have a package I wrote with functions using sqlalchemy that I was able to use on one of my computers. I connected with this string:

```
driver = 'SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
engine_string = prefix + '://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + server + '/' + database + '?driver=' + driver
```

On another computer, I was not able to install the native client 11.0 which I understand is deprecated. I tried switching the value to

```
driver = 'ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server'
```

I got an error with that version

```
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

I then tried just a generic odbc connection with the windows utility and got the same error. I was able to get that odbc manager connection to work when I checked 'Trust Server Certificate'

This is probably not good long term, but is there a way to add that attribute to the first string I have above? I tried several variations, but nothing worked.

I was able to get a working connection with the following:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect( 
driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}', 
server = server, 
database = database, 
uid = username,
pwd = password, 
encrypt='no', 
trust_server_certificate='yes')
```

but that connection did not work with the package I wanted to use.
thanks!

Comment: Which driver are you actually using

Comment: AFAIK, "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" is still supported so perhaps you could just use that.

Comment: On the computer I had that was having giving me the error I had driver v18. On that machine I have v17 and 18 installed and have tried them both. On the first machine it had the native client driver that had been installed previously (don't know when it was installed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connection error is due to a change in default behavior for the newest versions of SQL Server Drivers  (ODBC v18+, JDBC v10+, .Net Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v4.0+).

ODBC release notes: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228

The correct ODBC keyword to use is TrustServerCertificate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

just separate any extra arguments by an ampersand (&).
these will be translated to semicolons when the pyodbc connect string is generated internally

```
e=create_engine(“your args&Trusted_Connection=yes&TrustedServerCertificate=yes”)
```